# How to find 3x3 square matrix with maximum sum in bigger rectangular matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have matrix with size N x M and I want to find smaller matrix inside which has maximum sum and is of size 3 x 3. I can manually sum all the elements but wthis is imposible in bigger matrices, can you point me a better approach.

Comment: It means I want the 3x3 matrix with the biggest sum.

Comment: You can *calculate* the indices for that 3x3 matrix: `[x,y], [x+1,y], [x, y+1], [x+1, y+1]` and so on. Then loop over all possible submatrices

Comment: Have you done something so far?

Comment: And the problem with iteration on every inner matrix is a performance?

Comment: Can the matrix be modified? Also, what should happen if multiple submatrices sum to the same maximum?

Comment: Ok, matrix can't be modified. I know I can calculate indices but I wondered if there was better solution to this problem.

Comment: Question is unclear and public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for Kadane 2D algorithm.
I think it is one of the best solution for this problem

Comment: I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**Given**

```
public static int FindStuff(int[,] array)
{
   var largest = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0) - 2; i++)
   for (var j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1) - 2; j++)
   {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var x = i; x < i+3; x++)
      for (var y = j; y < j+3; y++)
         sum += array[x, y];
      if (sum > largest)
         largest = sum;
   }

   return largest;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var array = new[,]
{
   {1, 1, 1, 1},
   {1, 2, 3, 4},
   {1, 1, 1, 1},
   {5, 1, 1, 1},
};
Console.WriteLine(FindStuff(array));
```

**Result**

```
16
```

Comment: Nice I will try this

Answer (score 0):

In pure C# you must calculate all inner matricies, you can speed up algorithms with paraller task, you can also use CUDA, and a naive solution with checking inner matrices should looks like this:

```
public void TestMethod(int[][] matrix)
{
    int largestSum = 0;
    int columnLargestIdx = 0;
    int rowLargestIdx = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix.Length; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix[column].Length; row++)
        {
            if (IsBuild3x3Possible(matrix, column, row))
            {
                int sum = CalculateSum(matrix, column, row);
                if (sum > largestSum)
                {
                    largestSum = sum;
                    columnLargestIdx = column;
                    rowLargestIdx = row;
                }
            }
        }
}

public bool IsBuild3x3Possible(int[][] matrix, int column, int row)
{
    var columns = (matrix.Length - column) >= 3;
    var rows = (matrix[column].Length - row) >= 3;
    return columns && rows;
}

public int CalculateSum(int[][] matrix, int column, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = column; i < column + 3; i++)
        for (int j = row; j < row + 3; j++)
            sum += matrix[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```